# If I say my profession is x, does that imply I am employed right now?

Tags: word-usage

I am not employed right now but I'd like to communicate that if I work, I'd work as x.

**I don't want them to think I am currently working.**

Is there a better phrase than

> My profession is x

?

Comment: _I have experience working as an X_ or, if you are professionally qualified, _I am a professional X_.

Comment: Saying 'My profession is X', when one is not currently practicing it, is likely to be misleading, even though it may arguably still be true. If one wishes to convey what one's profession is and avoid misleading the audience in this way, one has to say something more elaborate.

Comment: 'Craig Miller, an actor currently between roles ...'.

Answer (score 2):

Stating your profession doesn't have to mean that you are currently employed; it indicates your normal line of work and/or your skill set. If you want to state what your normal job/vocation is but that you're not currently working, you could say

> I'm a computer programmer, though I'm currently between jobs.

You would normally only say this if you are actively pursuing that profession as a career, though. You wouldn't say

> I'm a cashier, though I'm currently between jobs.

...as 'cashier' isn't considered the kind of job that needs specialist skills or knowledge.

Comment: In other words, there is a difference in this respect between professions, in the strict sense, and occupations; being a cashier is not a profession.

Comment: @jsw29 Correct. Per Merriam-Webster's definition 4a "A calling requiring specialised knowledge and often long an intensive academic preparation" or b "A principle calling, vocation, or employment". I suppose that if a person has really dedicated themselves to being an incredible cashier, and actively seeks out that role, you could call it a profession at that point; most cashiers are not so focused.

Comment: Agree that a profession is a skill set, a qualification,  a dedication to an activity and so forth. But the phrase “between jobs” is not clear. It may be a euphemism for “unemployed” or it may mean that the next job exists but has not been started yet.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. *Is* implies present tense. E.g.

> I am a blacksmith.

Clearly indicates that you are currently a practicing blacksmith.

> I was a blacksmith.

Indicates that you were a practicing blacksmith (though ambiguous on the implication in the present).

> I had been a blacksmith.

Indicates that you were a practicing blacksmith in the past but no longer are.

If you don't want to be misleading, you should indicate that you were practicing your profession in the past but not in the present, using past perfect tense.

Comment: This isn't how job titles work in English (or any other language I know). "I am a blacksmith" means either I am in employment (possibly on holiday, on sabbatical, on maternity/paternity leave, doing vocational training, etc), or I'm looking for work as a blacksmith, or maybe I've recently finished working as a blacksmith and intend to do it again quite soon.

Comment: @StuartF The question isn't for job titles (e.g. CEO). It's for professions (e.g. Doctor). Saying that you are a CEO when looking for work as a CEO is definitely wrong.

Comment: @uberhaxed your example, of doctor, undermines your position. A doctor is a doctor, even if they're not currently working as a doctor.

Comment: @Werrf is a pro athlete, such as a basketball player, still a pro athlete when they are retired? For example, Magic Johnson retired and became a sport correspondent but would be referred to as a former althlete. And all of this is besides the point. The OP specifically asked for phrasing that makes it unambiguous that they are not currently employed in their profession.

Comment: @uberhaxed OP asked for phrasing that communicates that "if I work, I'd work as X". Your options - "I was a blacksmith" or "I had been a blacksmith" do not convey that. "I am a blacksmith, but currently between jobs" does.

Comment: @Werrf I think the OP was looking for something brief, otherwise they would use the long sentence written in the OP. And that aside, the OP emphasized (bolded) the portion of the question I was answering, so it would be incorrect to say that OP asked for "if I work, I'd work as X" over "I don't want them to think I am currently working". Obviously, if the OP wanted a sprawling phrase they would just say "If I work, I'd work as X" instead of asking their question.